# Is 1.31.0 or 222-1.18.0 the latest release of the google-api-services-youtube java client?

Tags: youtube-api

The [latest version on Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-youtube/v3) is 1.31.0

But the most recent google-api-services-youtube jar with an -rc suffix on maven.org is is version 3-rev222-1.18.0-rc: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-youtube/

And the [docs on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.Videos.List.html) still have revision 222 in the title

Answer (score 1):

From Google:

"The latest is ... youtube:v3-rev20210915-1.32.1.

The way to read our current version string: the v3 is the endpoint version - you'll find it in the REST documentation. The rev20210915 is the day the client was created and also when the discovery document was accessed. The 1.32.1 is the version of the client code."

Source:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/issues/10677